# Set Primary key and Foreign key constraint on a single column having type String in hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have 2 tables - Request and SubRequest. They both need to have one-to-one mapping. In the SubRequest table I need to have the Primary Key and the Foreign key on the same column (which is RequestID) . It is easily done in DB. My application uses hibernate. So in the hibernate mappings file I need to do the same. Also the requirement is that this key(RequestId) must be a varchar and generated by the application and not auto-generated by DB. I tried doing it from the following - 
http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-with-primary-key-xml-mapping-example
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/
But all of these have the id as Integer and auto-generated.
I could not make it work for RequestID which is a String.

Is it possible to do this in hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use uuid strategy, it will generate uuid as string id in your database, you don't need to set id, hibernate will take care of it.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid" )
private String id;
```

or use `@Id` without `@GeneratedValue` like

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME", nullable = false)
private String roleName;
```